# How to add different Development Targets in Ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ios-targets

In `iOS` development, we can add different `targets`. Which help us to maintain 2-3 different project on same theme. Compiled `target` takes it's own `resource` file.

I have a project with different `targets`. Each target have different image-resources and different `AppKeys` for `APIs`. So I can use one project for maintaining different `Apps`.

I want to implement same thing on `Ionic`. Is there any way to do that?

Simply I want to make conditional resource allocation.

here's the example of `iOS` `targets`[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be too large for me to develop as an answer, but generally the answer is yes. You can specify different assets or plugins depending on the target platform (quite easy for the icons for example). You can also do it inside the www folder programatically (detecting platform inside the code and switching cases). Some pre-compiling processes also allow you to skip parts of the code depending on constants you can define. It really depends on the type of asset, and what you consider a target